# How can I refer to a field of a class as some object, then use that object to obtain the field's value later?

Tags: c#

Say I have the following code

```
public class FooClass
{
    public int A { get; set; } = 0;
    public int B { get; set; } = 0;
}

public class BarClass
{
    public int X { get; set; } = 0;
    public int Y { get; set; } = 0;
}

public class MyClass
{
    int z = 0;
    public FooClass Foo { get; set; } = new FooClass();
    public BarClass Bar { get; set; } = new BarClass();

    public static void MyMethod()
    {
        // List of MyClass objects
        var myList = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(_ => new MyClass()).ToList();

        // Some flags set elsewhere
        bool getFooAValues = true;
        bool getBarYValues = true;
        bool getClassZValues = true;

        // Some statements that collects "field referecnes" of MyClass
        var classFieldReferenceList = new List<...>();
        if (getFooAValues)
            classFieldReferenceList.Add(...);
        if (getBarYValues)
            classFieldReferenceList.Add(...);
        if (getClassZValues)
            classFieldReferenceList.Add(...);

        // For each field reference
        classFieldReferenceList.ForEach(classFieldRef =>
        {
            // For each class
            myList.ForEach(myClassInst =>
            {
                // "Select"/"Apply" the reference to get the field value
                var fieldValue = myClassInt.getTheFieldReferenceValue(classFieldRef);

                // Do something with field value...
                return fieldValue;
            });

            // Do something with the list of field values...
        });
    }
}
```

In this code, specifically in `MyMethod`, I create a list of `MyClass` objects. This class has a few fields, some are simply primitive types, some are instances of other classes. **How can I refer to or address these fields in the form of some object I can pass around?**

For example, I began writing code, akin to the following

```
public static void MyMethod()
{
    // List of MyClass objects
    var myList = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(_ => new MyClass()).ToList();

    // Some flags set elsewhere
    bool getFooAValues = true;
    bool getBarYValues = true;
    bool getClassZValues = true;

    if (getFooAValues)
    {
        var Avalues = myList.Select(myClassInst => myClassInst.Foo.A);
        // Do Action X to list of values
    }
    if (getBarYValues)
    {
        var Yvalues = myList.Select(myClassInst => myClassInst.Bar.Y);
        // Do Action X to list of values
    }
    if (getClassZValues)
    {
        var Zvalues = myList.Select(myClassInst => myClassInst.z);
        // Do Action X to list of values
    }
}
```

Where `//Do Action X` was quite a few lines of code that I would perform to each set of values (Plotting values on a plot, flags represent showing plot line or not). Though, I don't really want duplicate that code for each possible field I could refer/address within `MyClass`. Thus, I want to refer to a field by some "object" then "apply" that object to an instance of `MyClass` later to get the value of the field, if that makes sense.

I feel like this might be akin to defining a `delegate`? Though the delegate would be specific to some class structure?.. Or maybe there is some simple solution I have confused myself out of finding.

Comment: If `AValues`, `Yvalues` and `ZValues` are always `IEnumerable<int>`, why not just `IEnumerable<int> values = null; if (...) values = myList.Select(myClassInst => myClassInst.Foo.A); if (...) values = myList.Select(myClassInst => myClassInst.Bar.Y).......`?

Comment: Sorry, that was just a semi-misleading example code. It will not always be `int`, it was just the fastest to type up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Func<MyClass,object>` delegate:

```
var classFieldReferenceList = new List<Func<MyClass,object>>();
if (...)
    classFieldReferenceList.Add(m => m.Foo.A);
if (...)
    classFieldReferenceList.Add(m => m.Foo.B);
if (...)
    classFieldReferenceList.Add(m => m.Bar.X);
if (...)
    classFieldReferenceList.Add(m => m.Bar.Y);
```

This is not ideal because `object` is used as the most common denominator, but that would be required for a "mixed bag" of types.

In your second example you could get away with a generic method:

```
private void DoActionsOnSelectedFields<T>(IEnumerable<MyClass> data, Func<MyClass,T> selector) {
    foreach (T val in data.Select(selector)) {
        ... // Perform some common action
    }
}
```

Comment: Add, this makes sense, I like that. I guess I probably should've seen the utility of `Func` in my example.